# Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.190.0

Tags: react-native, flipper

I have a react native app using react-native@0.71.7 and I am having a heck of a time getting redux-flipper working.  Part of the instructions are to explicitly include the react-native-flipper dependency.  I don't mind this as I can follow the [instructions to use the latest flipper sdk](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/#using-the-latest-flipper-sdk), rather than the older version that ships with react-native.

However that causes an error in the build for android.
`Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.190.0`

I can't seem to figure out how to upgrade flipper unless I downgrade to a previous version.  (I got 0.177.0 working).

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer to this!  Flipper is no longer building flipper-fresco so the versions are not synced. React native assumes they are and has the following in the app/build.gradle file

`debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")`

Since fresco is no longer in sync you need to lock it in. The latest version I found in maven was 0.182.0 so change the build.gradle to.

`debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.182.0")`

Comment: I also had to replace all other `debugImplementation`'s with `${FLIPPER_VERSION}` to 0.182.0 for it to work but this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The current official solution is to update your android/gradle.properties file with the following, anything higher than version 0.182.0 will fail at the moment

```
# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.182.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **any** version of Flipper by forcing Fresco plugin to use the latest known version:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.182.0'
  }
}
```